# Java Script: Assignment operator not working for a matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to populate a matrix that I declared with random variables, but for some explicable reason the random values aren't being assigned to the cells in the Matrix. 
Here is the declaration of said matrix:

```
this.weights_ih= new Matrix(this.hidden_nodes,this.input_nodes);
```

Please Keep in mind that this declaration is is part of a constructor of a class as shown below:

```
    class NeuralNetwork
    {
        constructor (input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes)
        {
            this.input_nodes=input_nodes;
            this.output_nodes=output_nodes;
            this.hidden_nodes=hidden_nodes;
            this.weights_ih= new Matrix(this.hidden_nodes,this.input_nodes);
            this.weights_ho= new Matrix(this.output_nodes,this.hidden_nodes);
            this.weights_ih.randomize();
            this.weights_ho.randomize();
            this.bias_h= new Matrix(this.hidden_nodes,1);
            this.bias_0= new Matrix(this.output_nodes,1);
            this.bias_h.randomize();
            this.bias_0.randomize();
            this.learning_rate=0.1;

        }
  }
```

The `randomize()` function returns a value between 1 and -1 and the definition is given below:

```
randomize()
    {
        for(let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {

            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                this.data[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*2 -1);
            }
        }

    }
```

I have made sure that the `randomize()` is working as I did console log the variable `this.data[i][j]`. Here is the screen shot of that:
[image: OutPut]
Therefore I assumed that the randomize() was not to blame as it was generating random values as expected and the data was being assigned to `this.data[i][j]`.
But when I tabled the matrix `this.weights_ih`. This was the output I received:
[image: Matrix]
I really do not understand why all the cells are undefined as in the `randomize()`values were being assigned to the variable `this.data[i][j]`.
Do let me know if I've made an error.
Here's the Matrix class definition if that in any way might help you:

```
class Matrix
{
    constructor (rows,cols)
    {
        this.rows=rows;
        this.cols=cols;
        this.data=[];
        for(let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {
            this.data[i]=[];
            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                let temp=this.data[i];
                temp[j]=0;
                //this.data[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    static transpose(matrix)
    {
        let result = new Matrix(matrix.cols,matrix.rows)

        for (let i=0;i<matrix.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<matrix.cols;j++)
            {
                result.data[j][i]=matrix.data[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
    toArray()
    {
        let arr=[];
        for(let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                arr.push(this.data[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    static fromArray(arr)
    {
        let m= new Matrix(arr.length,1);
        let v= arr.length;
        for(let i=0;i<v;i++)
        {
            m.data[i][0]=arr[i];
        }
        return m;
    }
    randomize()
    {
        console.log("Rows:"+this.rows+"cols"+this.cols);
        for(let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                this.data[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*2 -1);
            }
        }
    }
    static subtract(a,b)
    {
        let result= new Matrix(a.rows,a.cols);
        for( let i=0;i<result.rows;i++)
            {
                for(let j=0;j<result.cols;j++)
                {
                    result.data[i][j]=a.data[i][j]-b.data[i][j];
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
    add(n) 
    {
        if(n instanceof Matrix)
        {
            for( let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
            {
                for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
                {
                    this.data[i][j]+=n.data[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for( let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
            {
                for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
                {
                    this.data[i][j]+=n;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static multiply(a,b)
    {
        if(a.cols!==b.rows)
            {
                console.log("Error 001");
                return undefined;
            }
            let result = new Matrix(a.rows,b.cols);
            let sum=0;

            for(let i=0;i<result.rows;i++)
            {
                for(let j=0;j<result.cols;j++)
                {
                    sum=0;
                    for(let k=0;k<a.cols;k++)
                    {
                        sum+=a.data[i][k]*b.data[k][j];
                    }
                    result.data[i][j]=sum;
                }

            }
            return result;
    }
    multiply(n)
    {
        for( let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                this.data[i][j]*=n;
            }
        }
    }
    map(func)
    {
        //Apply a fucntion to every element 
        for( let i=0;i<this.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<this.cols;j++)
            {
                let val = this.data[i][j];
                this.data[i][j]=func(val);
            }
        }
    }
    static map(matrix,func)
    {
        let result= new Matrix(matrix.rows, matrix.cols);
        for(let i=0;i<matrix.rows;i++)
        {
            for(let j=0;j<matrix.cols;j++)
            {
                let val= matrix.data[i][j];
                result.data[i][j]=func(val);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    print()
    {
        console.table(this.data);
    }
}
```

NeuralNetwork Declaration:

```
function setup()
{
    let nn= new NeuralNetwork(2,2,2);
    let input=[1,0];
    let targets=[1,1];
    nn.train(input,targets);
}
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: You called `console.table` with no arguments?

Comment: Nope in the print() i called console.table with this.data as the argument. Code:print()
    {
        console.table(this.data);
    }

Comment: _"why all the cells are undefined"_ - They are not `undefined` but `NaN`. That's an important difference, because `Math.floor(Math.random()*2 -1)` won't ever return `NaN`

Comment: @Andreas what could return NaN?

Comment: Anywhere between `this.weights_ih.randomize();` and `this.weights_ih.print();` you're messing with the data. Get your debugger and step through your code. I won't list all possible operations that could return `NaN`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your NeuralNetwork declaration? And which method you call to get a error? I did "var n = new NeuralNetwork(10,10,10)" and "this.n.weights_ih.print()" and it shows me a perfect table with 0 an -1... Also works with others props like "this.n.bias_0.print()"

Comment: @CharlesAssuncao Hey ive added the neural network declaration at the bottom of the question and that works for me too. But I cant get the matrixes in the Neural network classes randomly initialised. Thanks

Comment: Try commenting out the `nn.train()` call and see whether it still logs `NaN`. If not, that call is to blame.

Comment: @Bergi yeah without nn.train() the function does work